# C++ 'std::stod': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, templates, std

I have the following code

```
template <typename T>
    void searchHistory( T searchValueMin, T searchValueMax){

        if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string)){ // If input search values are string
            try{

                double searchValueMinDouble = std::stod(searchValueMin);
                double searchValueMaxDouble = std::stod(searchValueMax);

                for (const auto& transaction : this->history) {
                    const double transactionAmount = std::stod(transaction->getValue());

                    if (transactionAmount >= searchValueMinDouble && transactionAmount <= searchValueMaxDouble) {
                        std::cout << transaction->toString() << "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(std::exception&) {
                std::cout << ">- Your search input seems to be invalid." << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else{
            for (const auto& transaction : this->history) {
                T transactionAmount = transaction->getValue();

                if (transactionAmount >= searchValueMin && transactionAmount <= searchValueMax) {
                    std::cout << transaction->toString() << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Which is a template function belonging to a base abstract class, that will take in a number input , float, double, int or string. However, When I call the function from main and pass in strings it works fine. But I tried passing in 2 int variables and its giving me the error shown in the title, I ve tried searching online and people mention about constexpr, however this doesnt seen to work.

(this->history is just a vector of 'Transaction' class. transaction->getValue() returns a string that is a number e.g 1500.50)

Comment: what is `this` ? please post a [mcve]

Comment: `std::stod(searchValueMin);` -- Templates do not work this way.  You pass in an `int`, the entire template code will stick an `int` into the template, wherever `T` is specified.  You should be specializing the template for `int`.  Your `typeid` comparison has no effect on this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so is there anyway I can specify a certain output for strings?

Comment: ...or use `constexpr if`

Comment: Create a concrete, non-template function called `searchHistory` that takes `std::string` arguments.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number next to the if (type_id()) == ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie or would it be better 2 get rid of my string stuff from the current template and move it to another template but for string specilisezd version?

Comment: There is no need for a template to specialize a single type.  Just create a regular function of that type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie then why do we use template specilisation?

Comment: You have a choice of either function overloading or template specialization.  You use specialization where appropriate.  In your case, I see no reason to create two template functions, one for generic types and another only special for strings.  Look at your code also -- does the string code look anything like the non-string code?  If the code were similar, but just a couple of places were different, ok.  But it is totally different, thus IMO just create a brand new function with the same name.  There are also other options, such as passing a second template argument describing custom actions.

Comment: Bottom line -- using `typeid` in template code is a code smell or something is not right with the design of the template class/function

Comment: `typeid` is a runtime operation. For compile-time use `if constexpr` with `std::is_same_v` and similar templates